# How to do the Height of html tag Body on 100% of browser window size?

Tags: html, css, height

There is a problem: http://okna.wispo.ru/

It must be view like in Google Chrome browser. But in Opera 9.6.x and FF 3.5.x and Safari it don't.

How to fix it, tell me plz, somebody (or help).

As you can see in source, the rule "height: 100%" on tags html and body don't help.

[Here is link on CSS.](http://okna.wispo.ru/public/css/style.css)

Thanks a lot, for any help and focus!

Comment: You've set the `<body>` to be 100% via your reset.css. Since this is a "relative" sizing, the browser looks "up" in the DOM tree to find a parent element to base that size off of. In this case, the parent is the browser window, so you've set `<body>` to be 100% of the window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with green border? Set height to auto, or just del this rule from your css-file.

reset.css 21 line

Comment: Border for better visibility of problem.

Comment: Maaaaan!!! Can you explain me, wtf is that rule do this affect? It works well! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: So, now, body stretch by content, but if content height is smaller then window size, the body height don't stretch to window.

Comment: height: 100% set the body size 100% of VISIBLE window. Your footer goes after body, in this case mean that after VISIBLE window. I'm not master of html but i hope that you understand me :)